# How can I make my text file go down the same line reading diifernt inputs

Tags: c++

I need to have my output look like this.

```
Applicant #: 1
School = L GPA = 4.0 math = 600 verbal = 650 alumnus = N
Applying to Liberal Arts
Accepted to Liberal Arts!!!
```

But when I run the code it just puts the input into every single place without going down the text file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Open both input and output
    ifstream input;
    input.open("MP2input.txt.");
    ofstream output;
    output.open("MP2output.txt");

    // containers for any variables
    double app = 0;
    string pass;

    if(!input.fail())
    {
        do(input >> pass)
        {
            app++;
            output << "Application #" << app << endl;
             output << "School = " << pass <<  " GPA = "  << pass << " Math = " << pass << " Verbal = " << pass << " Alumnus = " << pass << endl;
        }
    }
    input.close();
    output.close();
}
```

The input must look like this

```
L 4.0 600 650 N
M 3.9 610 520 N
L 3.8 590 600 N
```

Output looks like this

```
Application #1
School = L GPA = L Math = L Verbal = L Alumnus = L
Application #2
School = 4.0 GPA = 4.0 Math = 4.0 Verbal = 4.0 Alumnus = 4.0
Application #3
School = 600 GPA = 600 Math = 600 Verbal = 600 Alumnus = 600
Application #4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
   do(input >> pass)
   {
       app++;
       output << "Application #" << app << endl;
        output << "School = " << pass <<  " GPA = "  << pass << " Math = " << pass << " Verbal = " << pass << " Alumnus = " << pass << endl;
   }
```

You read one string from the file and then print it mutliple times. `input >> pass` reads one word until it encounters a whitespace character. It is not clear how you expect `output << "School = " << pass <<  " GPA = "  << pass ...`  to print different entries from the file. Also you have a `do` without the `while`.

If you want to read multiple words from the file you rather need:

```
std::string school;
std::string GPA; 
// ... others ...
while(input >> school >> GPA) {
    app++;
    output << "Application #" << app << endl;
    output << "School = " << school <<  " GPA = "  << GPA << endl;
    // ... others ...
}
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you very much. Im new to coding and new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your input file is well formatted just update pass from input each time.

```cpp
int main()
{
   // Open both input and output
   ifstream input;
   input.open("MP2input.txt.");
   ofstream output;
   output.open("MP2output.txt");

   // containers for any variables
   double app = 0;
   string pass;

   if(!input.fail())
   {
       do(input >> pass)
       {
           app++;
           output << "Application #" << app << endl;
           output << "School = " << pass;
           input >> pass;
           output <<  " GPA = "  << pass;
           input >> pass;
           output << " Math = " << pass;
           input >> pass;
           output << " Verbal = " << pass;
           input >> pass;
           output << " Alumnus = " << pass << endl;
       }
   }
   input.close();
   output.close();
}
```

Better to be a little more robust and check input.fail() each time but that's a lot of typing ;-)